# Problema al obtener datos desde EXTRA_TEXT

Tags: java, android, string

En la empresa de diseño para la que trabajo tratamos de crear una aplicacion de mensajería privada la cual nos permita compartir diversas URL desde diferentes aplicaciones como redes sociales, de manera tal que al compartirla se agregue en el cuerpo del mensaje, para esto usamos diversos intent-filter para cada aplicacion deseada y tratamos de obtener dicha URL a través de un intent algo parecido a esto:

```
  Bundle ext = getIntent().getExtras()
  String URLX = ext.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
```

Mientras que tengo definido en el AndroidManifest.xml el `intent-filter` :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Nos encontramos en la duda de saber si este es el modo correcto de obtener dicha URL o imagen en el caso de algunas redes sociales, y de que manera se puede aplicar dicho intent/string para que complete de manera automática el campo EditText del cuerpo de mensaje una vez compartida. Espero haber podido explicarme de manera correcta y entendible.

Edito:

Estamos tratando de agregar la URL obtenida atravez del siguiente codigo:

```
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String URL = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
          et1.setText(URL);
```

Pero la aplicacion no esta dando los resultados buscados

Comment: Hola Mariano Martin algunos usuarios de la comunidad piensan que tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, y estas preguntas no son aceptadas aqui  [so.es] podrias reformularla para que cumpla esta politica :)

Comment: Mariano, esto funciona al realizar el envio de un email mediante Intent.createChooser(), agregué un ejemplo, es correcta la forma en que lo realizas si esto es lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate si con esto te podés orientar:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content
Hace poco necesite algo parecido y ahi esta muy bien explicado

Comment: Gracias Franco pero ya se reviso la documentación oficial pero no logramos los resultados deseados. Saludos

Comment: Te recomendaría  correr el logcat si la aplicacion no abre (alt+6) fijate si esta bien ordenado el codigo y si declaraste correctamente todo.

Answer (score 0):

Se recibe mediante:

```
  String textoRecibido = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Lo que estas definiendo es un filtro para que un tipo de contenido en este caso `text/plain` pueda ser abierto por tu aplicación:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
```

En este caso cuando se realicé el envio de un email por medio de **Intent.createChooser()** tu aplicación aparecería en la lista de aplicaciones que pueden manipular este tipo de contenido.

Este es un ejemplo de envio de email:

```
  String[] TO = {""}; //Direcciones email  a enviar.
  String[] CC = {""}; //Direcciones email con copia.

  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Tu Asunto...");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "tuemail@email.com"); // * configurar email aquí!

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email."));        
     Log.i("EMAIL", "Enviando email...");
  }
  catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "NO existe ningún cliente de email instalado!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Al realizar el envio, aparecería una pantalla, donde tu puedes realizar la selección del cliente para envío del email, incluida tu aplicación ya que tiene definido el `intent-filter` para realizar esta acción para este tipo de contenido (`text/plain`) .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa la documentación ["Recibir datos de otras aplicaciones" (inglés)](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Elenasys pero no es lo que busco, en este caso no es enviar información, sino recibirla, y estamos realmente muy preocupados por no poder lograrlo. No encontramos la manera ya hace días, y no sabemos donde mas recurrir

Comment: Quisiera agregar que la documentación ya la revisamos varias veces e igual no encontramos el método correcto, con el código que agregue al pie de mi pregunta, la aplicacion no abre en ningún momento, da error al intentar iniciar, saludos

Comment: Lo que desean es enviar un dato (url)  de una aplicación a otra?

Comment: Exactamente, un ejemplo seria al compartir un e-mail desde la aplicacion de Gmail, nuestra aplicacion aparece en la lista, sin las lineas agregadas al activity al seleccionarla abre nuestra aplicacion solo que no tiene función, al agregar las lineas para que dicho texto sea transcrito al campo EditText la aplicacion directamente no ejecuta, alguna idea de que nos esta faltando?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, dejo el código por si alguien lo necesita a futuro

```
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();
    String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
    //make sure it's an action and type we can handle
    if(receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)){

    }
    else if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)){

    }

    String receivedText = receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    //check we have a string
    if (receivedText != null) {
        //set the text
        et1.setText(receivedText);
    }
```